# iCloud Setting Page Value

Tags: icloud

I am a new apple user and I just signed in to iCloud. I see some strange values in my setting page.

[image: iCloud strange dollar values]

What's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you expect to see? Those are European number formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are just *examples* of what dates, times, numbers and money formats will be respectively in your iCloud account. If you don't want those formats there should be settings to allow you to change them in iCloud. Otherwise you can just ignore it.